# Keyboard doesn't close after Cancel button SearchBar Ionic 2

Tags: ios, ionic2, keyboard, searchbar, cancel-button

I am implementing `searchbar` in `Ionic 2`. When I run the app in iOS, in simulator or on a real device it doesn't work properly. When I click `Cancel` the keyboard closes at first and then reopens again. The `searchbar`, still has the cursor in it.

This what I have done.

.html

```
  <ion-searchbar 
    placeholder = "Kerko"
    (keyup.enter)="search(q.value)"
    [showCancelButton]="true" 
    (ionCancel)="reset($event)"
  ></ion-searchbar>
```

.ts

```
  constructor(private navCtrl:NavController,
    public keyboard: Keyboard,
     private platform: Platform) {

  }

  search(q: string) { 
    console.log(q); 
    this.navCtrl.push(SearchPage, {"query": q});
  }

  reset(event) {   

    this.keyboard.close();

  }
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Run `ionic cordova plugin ls`.  Do you see cordova-plugin-ionic-webview in the output?  I bet you that it is incompatibility with ios 11 and old webview.  If you do not see it I would recommend [installing it](http://blog.ionic.io/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/).

Comment: If I use WKWebView (latest version), it gives me an error with CORS and background notification (I have used FCM for notifications)

Comment: A CORS issue is documented in their transition guide (might be yours).  For fun I tried using your ion-searchbar with the latest ionic 3 using WKWebView and it works fine. I am not really sure how to address your issue using the older web view as I tried to address a similar issue for a couple hours on my last app before deciding to upgrade for IOS11.

Comment: I resolved CORS problem (since I own the server), but the FCM still gives problems. Notification does come, but when I click on it, it doesn't do anything. The code responsible for the doing something after a notification is received doesn't do anything.